# ::part() in polymer is not compatible with Microsoft-Edge

Tags: css, google-chrome, polymer, microsoft-edge, polymer-2.x

I am developing a web-component project based on polymer 2.0. 
I am using the part concept in polymer to differentiate different aspect of an element. Since I need different style to a specific part, I am applying style to this specific part using ::part() after importing this to other HTML files.

Sample code is as followed.

```
<customElement>
<div part="samplePart">
demo
</div>
//other tags
</customElement>
```

And style element is as followed.

```
customElement::part(samplePart){
//some styles
}
```

This approach is working fine in google chrome. But the problem is that when I am using Microsoft-edge browser, it is not reading the "part" element and applying whatever default style to the whole element.

Any idea how to achieve this in Edge?  I do not prefer changing the HTML part as I am importing this element to multiple independent files which need different styling.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the polymer document](https://www.polymer-project.org/), I create a sample and test the code, I could reproduce the problem, but from the official document and [polymer issues](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues), I'm not finding the solution for this issue, I suggest you could contact polymer team or post this issue to [the polymer issues](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues).

As a workaround, you could try to use the following code to add css style for the samplePart:

```
customElement > div[part='samplePart'] {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: antiquewhite
}
```

Comment: I have posted this issue to the polymer issue. As of today, ::part() CSS syntax is only supported in Chrome.  

For reference: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/5532